# What is netgear ProSAFE and where can I find documentation of this feature?

Tags: netgear

I have several netgear switches with ProSAFE feature, but the only piece of official information about ProSAFE i found is this:

https://kb.netgear.com/31233/What-is-a-ProSAFE-Web-Managed-Switch

> NETGEAR ProSAFE Web Managed Switches (previously called ProSAFE Unmanaged Plus Switches) are an upgrade from unmanaged switches. ProSAFE Web Managed Switches are plug-and-play for easy deployment, but also support additional configuration and monitoring features using a web browser-based GUI.

But nowhere can I find information on how to use it or what the feature set is.

Can anyone explain the feature, how to use it and maybe where to find documentation on it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a feature, it's simply a name for that product line of switches.

Comment: To add a source from Netgear: [What is a ProSAFE Web Managed Switch?](https://kb.netgear.com/31233/What-is-a-ProSAFE-Web-Managed-Switch) or [ProSafe: The Professional Choice](https://tools.netgear.com/prosafe/)

Comment: But I don‘t find any socumentation of these features. @yoonix The second link you posted mentions SNMP but the documentation of the ProSAFE switches i have (GS105 and GS108 ProSAFE) don‘t mention anything about it. Also no documentation on how to access the supposedly existing web gui (they don‘t show up in my dhcp server and as layer 2 switches i wouldn‘t expect them to either)

Comment: You have an unmanaged switch, a different model than the documentation you are referring to. https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS108.aspx#docs